# Twitter API: Age of Twitter Users

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Is it possible to get Twitter Users' ages via any of their API's? Does Twitter share this sensitive information?

I know that people have tried to predict the ages of users, because ages are not retrievable in the past (https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0183537), but I was wondering if this is still the same.

*Follow up question:* Does Twitter filter the tweets of users with ages over 18 via the API's?

Edit: I checked the API documentation before asking this question, and I didn't find anything there relating to age. I merely wanted to see if anyone else knew of this from experience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not technical support for Twitter.

Comment: The docs should know

Comment: @WaiHaLee Where do you say I should post it instead?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. You could maybe look in https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs.html but I'm not at all sure.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I did and there is no mention of this, which is why I asked if anyone knew more. Isn't that the point of question-and-answer site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter's API does not provide any information about a user's age, as you should be able to discover from the developer website.